# Why this CSS code doesn't repeat the background?

Tags: html, css

```
.square2 {
  background-image: url(favicon.png);
  background-size: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid;
  text-shadow: white 0px 0px 2px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

The image is a 32x32 pixel favicon. Now this is from w3schools:

> By default, a background-image is placed at the top-left corner of an
>   element, and repeated both vertically and horizontally.

The background-size property specifies only the width, and the height is auto, so how do I know if my code will repeat the background or not? Here it could have repeated it vertically. And in this code here it repeats it:

```
<div class="tiledBackground">
</div>

.tiledBackground {
  background-image: url(https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/8971/firefox_logo.png);
  background-size: 150px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid;
  color: pink;
}
```

Here the width is set to 150px but the height is also auto, so why it doesn't stretch the image? The image is a 2982x2808 Firefox logo.

Comment: Have you already tried already "background-repeat: repeat;"?

Comment: My intention is not to repeat the background. I'm trying to understand in which conditions it will repeat the background.

Comment: To answer your second question, "why doesn't the image stretch" thats because the "background-size" sets the width and height to a maximum when only provided with 1 argument. learn more about this on https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Answer (score 2):

The 32x32 favicon would be repeating if you made the width/height of the container bigger or made the background-size smaller like this (making the background-size 32px (or you can just remove that property if you actually just want it to be the default size of the image):

```
.square2 {
  background-image: url(favicon.png);
  background-size: 32px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid;
  text-shadow: white 0px 0px 2px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

Similarly, the 2nd example you posted is working the same way but setting the background image to 150px width in a 300x300px container.

To repeat vertically only use:

```
background-repeat: repeat-y;
```

Comment: Why not repeat vertically only? The height is auto and the width is fixed so in theory it can choose between repeating and not repeating it vertically. How do I know what is going to happen?

Comment: You'd need to set `background-repeat: repeat-y;` for that

Answer (score 1):

Background image is set to repeat by default. but to repeat a background image inside a div with fixed height and width, you can either :

1. choose an image which is smaller than the width and height of the div.
2. define background-size to value smaller than width and height of the div.

Here, I would also like to add that background-size:300px auto; or simply background-size: 300px; will fill the complete background of div without repeating it because size auto will always maintain the aspect ratio of the actual size of image.

In your first case your image size is 32X32px so background-size: 300px auto; will make the background-size: 300px 300px;

In your second case your image size is 2982X2808 px and your background-size: 150px. It will show the repeated background-image with size 150X141 px each.

Hope this help.

Comment: What is "the aspect ratio of the actual size of image"? Thanks for the helpful answer.

Comment: aspect ratio of actual size is 1:1

Comment: Also, please accept the answer if it helped so that it can help others as well.